# Single code can I execute in different mobile technologies Android, iPhone, Blackberry, Windows mobile

Tags: android, iphone, multiplatform

I am Android developer. Can I run my app in different mobile technologies ex. iPhone, Blackberry, Windows mobile etc. I write code for android but I have not any idea about iPhone development. So I want to install my same app in iPhone mobile also. As well as any technology available for one time write code for app and spread and execute this in different technologies. Is this possible now that time. please help me. Thank you!

Comment: why was there a downvote? interesting question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use [PhoneGap](http://phonegap.com/) .

> Phonegap gives you the freedom to create mobile applications for iOS,
>   Android, Blackberry, Windows Phone, Palm WebOS, Bada and Symbian using
>   the web code you know and love: HTML, CSS and Javascript.

Comment: Thank you for answer. Can you provide important links for that. Specially for beginners

Comment: @RanjitChandel I already posted link . Click on PhoneGap.